# DropDown a View in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react native and I want an accordion library to use. Can't find any till now.
Please help I'm stuck. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did update the answer.
You mean accordion or collapsible view:

[react-native-collapsible](http://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible.)

Comment: But this is not a popup. These Libraries are used for Popups

Comment: oh you mean accardeon! see this: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible. I didn't figured out the image! it is opened now when refresh!

Comment: Exactly! Thank You!